# Back up of ITunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipod-touch

This may seem a silly question... but ITunes when synced with my Iphone, only backs up into my main PC correct?  In other words, when I hook up to Itunes on my computer all the info goes into that computer.  When someone uses my Apple ID on another PC for Itunes and syncs or backs up their IPOD or phone only the music will download yes? Not the SMS messages or photos? Those are stored on my hard drive?

I ask only because someone was able to use my ICloud to sync to my phone with their Ipod and pulled all my text messages etc off of it. I get that on the Cloud its a shared thing but anything that was synced to my Itunes (other than what was on my ICloud) would stay in the primary computer hard drive?

I have looked everywhere thru forums to answer this question as basic as it seems. Im probably overthinking it all.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a silly question because syncing and sharing are complicated.

iCloud is able to sync across devices: Safari bookmarks, reading list, open tabs; calendars, reminders, tasks; contacts; documents; mail, notes; the newest 1000 photos; keychain passwords (soon); **iTunes music, movies, TV shows, apps, and books**. (That is the short list!)

So, depending on the devices' settings, someone with your Apple ID and password could gain access to any of this stuff. Therefore, take care of your passwords and make them great.

iTunes does store your stuff on the device but turning on iCloud means you will share it. Go to iCloud.com, sign it and take a look. Take a look at iCloud preferences (properties) or settings.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I get what you are looking for, but let me present two ideas and see if that helps you resolve your questions:

1. You can take one iOS device and connect it to n different iTunes - each of which would make a full backup of the device. You don't need to sync to back up, and the device can require that iTunes encrypt the backup. Furthermore, if your device has a passcode, iTunes cannot back things up until that passcode is presented (or if that computer already syncs to the device and has a key to begin syncing even when the passcode has the device locked).
2. Backup to iCloud is 100% independent of backup to iTunes. One can be on and the other can still happen and turning on or off iCloud backup doesn't go and erase any backups that exist on any computer. That computer also won't sync that backup to iCloud as the files are stored outside the cloud locally.

   - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4946